# get column names using criteria and column value using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sub_id': [101,101,101,102,102,103,104],
                   'test_status':['Y','N','Yes','No','Not sure','NOT SURE','YES'],
                   'remarks':[np.nan,"testvalue",np.nan,"ilike","wild",np.nan,"test"],
                   'reg_value':['YES','NO','Y','N','SURE','YES','no'],
                   'TEST':['RES','YES','SAF','YWQTEU','JHLK','1265','QEEU']})
```

Basically, I would like to do the below

a) Get the names of the columns whichever has only values from the `response` list given below

```
response = ['Y','y','YES','Yes','yes','NO','No','no','N','n','NOT SURE','Not sure','not sure','sure','SURE','Sure']
```

The column should not contain any other value except the ones mentioned in `response list`.

For ex: `column Test` should not be in ouptut because along with `YES`, it contains other values which are not in `response` list.

So, I tried the below but the output is incorrect. not sure how to exclude `TEST` column.

```
df.apply(lambda row: row[row.isin(response)].index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
op_col_list = ['test_status','reg_value']
```

So, I have two questions

a) How to exclude `TEST` column for being considered?

b) How to make `response` list elegant. As you can see the values are repeating due to uppper and lower case representation. Is there anyway to make a list case-insensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isin` and keep only columns where all rows are True:

```
>>> df.columns[df.isin(response).all()].tolist()
['test_status', 'reg_value']
```

Modify `response` to be more elegant:

```
resp = fr"({'|'.join(set([r.lower() for r in response]))})
```

```
>>> df.select_dtypes('object').columns[df.select_dtypes('object').stack()
                                         .str.fullmatch(resp, case=False)
                                         .unstack().all()].tolist()

['test_status', 'reg_value']


>>> resp
'(sure|not sure|yes|y|no|n)'
```

Comment: @TheGreat. I updated my answer. Now `response` is more elegant :-)

Answer (score 1):

To handle the case insensitivity we can use [`str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html) with `case=False`:

```
# These can be any case:
response = ['Y', 'YES', 'NO', 'N', 'NOT SURE', 'SURE']

# Create a Regex pattern:
pattern = f'{"|".join(response)}'

# Apply to DataFrame columns
# (selected using loc can choose only columns needed):
cols = (
    df.loc[:, 'test_status':'reg_value']
        .apply(lambda s: s.str.fullmatch(pattern, case=False).all())
)

# Filter With Results:
cols = cols.index[cols].tolist()
```

`cols` before filter:

```
test_status     True
remarks        False
reg_value       True
dtype: bool
```

`cols` after filter and `tolist`:

```
['test_status', 'reg_value']
```

*`fullmatch` will check the cell contains *only* the value in the pattern. Can also use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) if looking for cells which contain a response value.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you if you want to make it case insensitive:

```py
response_lower = ['yes', 'not sure', 'n', 'y', 'no', 'sure']

searched_features = []
for feature in df:
    if df[feature].map(str).str.lower().isin(response_lower).mean() == 1:
        searched_features.append(feature)
searched_features
```